# rpy2 - Error in sqrt(e.pow) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using a robust stats package from Rand Wilcox from within rpy2 and hitting a snag when running a robust test for comparing n groups.

The following function takes a DataFrame, and as far as I can tell from the docs, integers representing the columns for the dependent variable and the groups assignments:

```
wilcox.btrim(df,g=2,dp=1)
```

When I run it from rpy2, I get the error:

```
Error in sqrt(e.pow) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

The same error occurs if, as the first and only input, I pass a list of lists or a df where each column contains the group values. Both of these are also suitable ways of calling the function.

This is my DataFrame:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x = random.choices(x, k=150)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 150)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dependent_variable': y,
    'group_labels': x
})

df.head(10)

dependent_variable  group_labels
       -1.258020         1
        0.357578         3
        0.809774         1
        0.330426         3
       -0.210970         2
```

This is how to get the package so that you are able to reproduce the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import random
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
pandas2ri.activate()


url = urlopen('https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/239/docs/Rallfun-v35.txt')
string = b''.join(url.readlines()).decode()
wilcox = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(string, "wilcox")
```

Any idea what is going on here?